# android: widget: service:: How to update widget and activity control's text/image from service

Tags: android, service

I have service, widget and activity....widget and activity both have one textview which should display same string. String is produced by service.

Is there any way to update both using single command or message from service?

Does `RemoteView` usefull in this, How? Any links to example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a broadcast receiver in the activity. When the service gets the string, creates intent with the string, ACTION, and sends it to all listeners.

Comment: Hey @Pepi you got any example links for this approach ?